# Где ошибка в коде при создании telegraf-bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, telegram

бот должен реагировать на команду /напомни ***действие*** в ***часы:минуты***

подозреваю, что проблема где-то здесь `bot.on(/\/напомни (.+) в (.+)/, (msg, match) => {`

пытался менять команду на `bot.hears()`, `bot.onText()`, но безрезультатно.

```
    const Telegraf = require('telegraf');
const bot = new Telegraf("token");

var notes = [];

bot.on(/\/напомни (.+) в (.+)/, (msg, match) => {
var userId = msg.from.id;
var text = match[1];
var time = match[2];
console.log('err1');
notes.push({
    "uid": userId,
    "time": time,
    "text": text
});

bot.sendMessage(userId, "Отлично! Я обязательно напомню, если не сдохну ");
});

setInterval(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
        var curDate = new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes();
        if (notes[i]['time'] == curDate) {
            bot.sendMessage(notes[i]['uid'], 'Напоминаю, вы должны: ' + notes[i]['text'] + 'сейчас.');
            notes.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы забыли прописать 
`bot.start()`